# Unable to create new Prism project in a solution

Tags: c#, prism

I have a solution with a number of prism projects in all created and working fine. Im trying to create a new prism project and its giving the error:

The vstemplate file references the wizard class Prism.visualStudio.wizards.selectcontainerwizard. which does not exist in the assembly Prism.visualstudio.wizards version =1.0.0.0.

I have tried reinstalling the prism templates pack view the manage extensions with no change.
btw i have prism template pack 2.3.0 installed

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please paste the exact error here and if possible your piece of code?

Comment: ive typed the error message as it was displayed. no code was relevant, i was creating a new project. Ive posted the solution below if your interested. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully this helps someone else. After checking my visualstudio install found it needed updating to 16.8.3,  Ran update, relaunched VS an all is good and working fine